# Dois eventos em função - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho uma função em `jQuery` da qual faço por meio do evento `.on('change')` , mas eu precisava também que essa mesma função acontecesse no carregamento da página, porém não sei como fazer isso, chamar dois eventos em uma função.

**Código da função em `jQuery`:**

```
$j("#fullname").on('change',function(){
    alert("Teste");
});
```

Comment: Pode dar  um `trigger` na própria declaração 

`$("#fullname").on('change',function(){alert("Teste");}).trigger('change');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi o que você quer, basta você criar uma `função`, assim você pode executar ela no carregamento da pagina e no `click`, `change` ou qualquer outra forma que queira executar.

```js
function funcao(name){
  alert('Meu nome é: ' + name)
}

$('#btn').on('click', function(){
  funcao('Rafael Augusto')
})

funcao('Rafael Augusto')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Clique aqui</button>
```

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo. Fiz do jeito que você disse e deu certo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Crie um `trigger` com o evento após o carregamento da página:

```
$j(window).on("load", function(){
    $("#fullname").trigger("change");
});
```

Isso irá disparar o evento `onchange` no elemento.

```js
$(window).on("load", function(){
 $("#fullname").trigger("change");
});
$("#fullname").on('change',function(){
    alert("Teste");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fullname">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```